# Making border for window with MoveToEx and LineTo

Tags: c, winapi, graphics

So I just got started with the win32 graphics since I wanted to work on an UI for an app I'm making. I basically wanted to draw a border on it, but for some reason the line is only drawn on the top and the left side. If anyone knows what's up, it'll be helpful.

code:

```
bool bRet = false;
HPEN pPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, Thickness, pColor);
HGDIOBJ hObj = SelectObject(*hDc, pPen);

bRet = MoveToEx(*hDc, pClient->left, pClient->top, 0);

bRet = LineTo(*hDc, pClient->right, pClient->top);
bRet = LineTo(*hDc, pClient->right, pClient->bottom);
bRet = LineTo(*hDc, pClient->left, pClient->bottom);
bRet = LineTo(*hDc, pClient->left, pClient->top);
bRet = LineTo(*hDc, pClient->bottom, pClient->top);

DeleteObject(hObj);
return bRet;
```

what it looks like:

[image: running the app]

Comment: You are calling DeleteObject with the wrong handle and forgetting to select the pen back out of the DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `bottom` and `right` in most box models are off by 1. So subtract 1 from them. Rigurously the border is not included in the size of the "*box*".

Comment: That's not correct. The true reason is, that rectangles are endpoint-exclusive in Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, you are clearly right! But now I can't delete the answer because it's accepted. I note that you are a windows developer, even your nick name is an interface.

Comment: Interfaces have been part of the Windows API for 25 years (see [Component Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)). [IInspectable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205821.aspx) is the new base interface for most Windows Runtime types, introduced in Windows 8. The Windows Runtime is the designated successor to the Windows API.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume, that `pClient` points to a [`RECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162897.aspx) structure, initialized through a call to `GetClientRect`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx) has the following to say:

> In conformance with conventions for the [**`RECT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897.aspx) structure, the bottom-right coordinates of the returned rectangle are exclusive. In other words, the pixel at (**right**, **bottom**) lies immediately outside the rectangle.

That's somewhat poorly worded. It's not just the pixel at (**right**, **bottom**) that lies outside the rectangle, but the entire column at (**right**, *<y>*) and the entire row at (*<x>*, **bottom**). To account for the fact, that pixels at coordinates `pClient->right` and `pClient->bottom` aren't part of the rectangle, subtract 1 from each when drawing:

```
BOOL bRet = FALSE;
HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, Thickness, pColor);
bRet = hPen != NULL;
HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hDc, hPen);

bRet &= MoveToEx(hDc, pClient->left, pClient->top, 0);

bRet &= LineTo(hDc, pClient->right - 1, pClient->top);
bRet &= LineTo(hDc, pClient->right - 1, pClient->bottom - 1);
bRet &= LineTo(hDc, pClient->left, pClient->bottom - 1);
bRet &= LineTo(hDc, pClient->left, pClient->top);

SelectObject(hDc, hOldPen);

DeleteObject(hPen);
return bRet;
```

Note the following other fixes to the code:

- The fifth call to `LineTo` didn't make sense. It has been removed.
- Invalid indirection of `hDc` (assuming that it is of type `HDC`) in the call to `SelectObject`.
- Properly restored the device context on exit.
- Properly deleted the pen created and owned by the code.
- Adjusted type and calculation of the return value. It should return `TRUE` only if **all** calls succeeded.
- Renamed `pPen` to `hPen` to follow established conventions.

---

Bonus reading:

- [Why are RECTs endpoint-exclusive?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040218-00/?p=40563)

Comment: ... OP: "Wait – there is *documentation* for this!?"